# Doesn't exist: WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, weboperationcontext

I am trying to use the following command in a silverlight application "WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add". However it doesnt appear to exist. I know it does exist because it is on the microsoft documention website. Here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.outgoingrequest.aspx. I am guessing that it is one of those functions not available in silverlight. Any ideas on why this Add function would not be available would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you are looking at the .NET versions of the API and not the silverlight one.

Comment: That is definitely possible. Thanks!

Comment: I still do not see the add function under the headers property on the silverlight Doc at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebrequestcontext(v=vs.95).aspx. If it helps I am trying to reproduce the example at the following blog on opening a microsoft document using silverlight: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/04/21/opening-an-microsoft-office-documents-with-silverlight/. I am trying to do the third step but it doesn't work because of this add function not existing